# "Reshape" along a specific axis - Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have a 4D numpy array. For example I have 2 batches of 3 two-dimensional matrices with a shape of (2, 3, 4, 5).
In each batch, I want to concatenate the three 2D matrices horizontally (over the last dimension).

The output shape should be of shape (2, 4, 5 * 3).

---

A smaller example for reproduction with shape (2, 3, 2, 2):

```
a1, a2, a3, a4 = 2, 3, 2, 2
arr = np.arange(a1*a2*a3*a4).reshape((a1, a2, a3, a4))

[[[[ 0  1]
   [ 2  3]]

  [[ 4  5]
   [ 6  7]]

  [[ 8  9]
   [10 11]]]


 [[[12 13]
   [14 15]]

  [[16 17]
   [18 19]]

  [[20 21]
   [22 23]]]]
```

It's first row (if examining the last dimension) should be: `[0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2,4,15)`.  or maybe `transpose(0,2,3,1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While some form of `concatenate` can be used, `transpose` often works for this kind of problem:

```
In [532]: arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2,2,6)
Out[532]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9],
        [ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21],
        [14, 15, 18, 19, 22, 23]]])
```

Without the final reshape, the first "line" is

```
In [533]: arr.transpose(0,2,1,3)
Out[533]: 
array([[[[ 0,  1],
         [ 4,  5],
         [ 8,  9]],
```

And for the example with all different dimensions

```
In [534]: x=np.ones((2,3,4,5))
In [535]: x.transpose(0,2,1,3).shape
Out[535]: (2, 4, 3, 5)
In [536]: x.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2,4,3*5).shape
Out[536]: (2, 4, 15)
```

Sometimes figuring out the transpose takes some tial-and-error.  But here you want to keep the first dimension as is, and also the last, so we are left with swapping the two middle ones.

By itself transpose makes a view, but the last reshape has to make a copy since it's reordering the 'raveled' values.

Comment: Very neat, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With doubled `np.hstack` (to collect horizontal rows through all matrices) and back to equivalent shape with `np.reshape`:

```
new_arr = np.hstack(np.hstack(arr)).reshape(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[2], -1)
```

---

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9],
        [ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21],
        [14, 15, 18, 19, 22, 23]]])
```

---

```
new_arr.shape
(2, 2, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the list comprehension this does not create an intermediate array and is a faster option compared to Roman's answer (at least in the experiments I ran with different sizes and shapes):

```
np.concatenate([arr[:, :, i] for i in range(arr.shape[2])]).reshape(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[2], -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Correct me if I'm wrong but the operations @hpaulj proposed create a view, which should not be expensive.
Also, my experiments the list comprehension solution was slightly slower (which makes sense imho).

Comment: hpaulj answer is definitely the best. The transpose operation creates a view. The reshape operation however might not, in this case. "e.g. transposed.base is arr -> True; reshaped.base is arr -> False"